# Stuck in an Exception loop

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am parsing through the HTML returned from a list of links. When I reach a certain point in each HTML document I raise an Exception.

```
import urllib2, time, 
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser2(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if somethings:
            do somethings
        if tag == "div" and "section2" in attrs[0][1]:
            raise NameError('End')

parser2 = MyHTMLParser2()
cntr = 0
for links in ls:
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(links)
        parser2.feed(f.read())
        cntr+=1
        if cntr%10 == 0:
            print "Parsing...", "       It has benn", (time.clock()-start)/60, 'mins.'
            break

    except Exception, e:
        print 'There has been an error Jim.    url_check number', cntr
        error_log.write(links)
        continue
```

It just executes the try statement once for the first link and then executes the exception clause to infinity.

How can I get it to move on to the next link once the exception is raised

The `error_log` is from some other errors it would run into related to `urllib2`, mostly they seemed like it wasn't able to connect to the webpage fast enough. So if there was a way to quit the `HTMLParser2` without throwing an exception, that would be great. That way I could re-implement the `error_log`

Comment: Can you print the traceback?

Comment: It's a bad idea to catch just `Exception`, as that will cause you to ignore unexpected errors. Only catch the most specific type of exception you can, and only if you actually have a reason to catch it.

Answer (score 2):

No, your diagnosis is not correct, there is not infinite exception loop here. Each URL is an entirely separate exception.

The `cntr` variable won't update whenever you have an exception, perhaps that is giving you the *impression* that you end up in a exception loop. Either move the `cntr += 1` line *out* of the `try:` statement, or use `enumerate()` to generate a counter for you.

That said, why are you trying to parse multiple HTML pages with one parser instance? Most likely the exception you keep getting is that a specific page is malformed and put the parser into a state it cannot continue from.

Answer (score 1):

You should not stop the parser with an exception. Parsing is a pretty complex process and usually, it's better to let the parser complete, collecting the information you need and process this information when the parser has done it's job. That way, you keep different things in your software separate, making everything easier to maintain, debug and understand.

Comment: I think you might be right. While I've got the loop to move on the the next link, the parser seems to be stuck on the first link, because its only returning the information I want from the first link. I figured I could save a few hours of parsing if I got the parser to quit early. But its going to take me a few hours to figure out how to get it to do that properly. Mine as well just let it run through.